# MesoColumn not able to retrieve data from Twitter ID

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Have anyone of you ever used wordpress theme mesocolumn.? Here is the screenshot:

[image: Mesocolumn Theme]

Now, in this theme, there is a widget called social counter. Which displays FB Fans, Twitter Followers, RSS Subscribers etc. Screenshot:

[image: Social Counter Widget as seen on AppLounge Website]

The configuration for this in Background is done like this screenshot:

[image: Background Configuration of Social Counter Widget]

Now my problem is that when I enter Twitter ID for my [this account](https://twitter.com/AppLoungeIn), which is **"1619550157"**, the widget is unable to retrieve the number of followers in my account, nor it sends to the Twitter account on click. Instead of that, if I use my Username, which is [AppLoungeIn](https://twitter.com/AppLoungeIn), it takes me to the Twitter account on clicking, but again unable to retrieve the number of followers from the site. In any case it is not showing the exact number of followers here on the website (although we can see its working fine with facebook and RSS feeds) Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong.?

To know in detail, see the image below and then go to [this link](http://www.applounge.in):

[image: AppLounge Website ScreensSnap]

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they have removed this feature from their latest update. So its no more a question I guess..

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have the Twitter information entered correctly. However, your Facebook data is wrong and is causing the link to be broken. Even though it is counting the correct number of likes, if you click that link, it takes you to https://www.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/AppLoungeIn

Just use your id (AppLoungeIn), not the full url.

As for the problem you are having with Twitter, it is really hard to tell what is going on without knowing the code they are using to generate this widget. In the version I downloaded, I didn't see the social widget at all, nor the images you are using. So without seeing that code, hard to know.

In general, first, I would correct the Facebook issue. Then give it a little time for Twitter to update (I've seen situations where the data didn't update right away). Clear your cache and try again. If that doesn't work, contact the theme's support since they created it. Unless you have a plugin controlling this, then contact them.